# How to export online content in QGIS print composer into static formats for offline use (eg: PNG, PDF)

Tags: qgis, print-composer, html

I have a print composer layout which, amongst other things, has a HTML frame with the following code:

```
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/27c6690f63.js"></script>

<ul class="fa-ul">
  <li><i class="fa-li fa fa-rss"></i><class="hidden">URL</class></li>
  <li><i class="fa-li fa fa-twitter"></i><class="hidden">URL</class></li>
  <li><i class="fa-li fa fa-facebook"></i><class="hidden">URL</class></li>
</ul>
```

This frame shows up fine on the screen after a short loading time (at least, most of the time, as from time to time it doesn't load and, hence, becomes empty), but my problem arises when I want to export all the atlas features using that frame into PNGs (or PDF, doesn't matter): everything is exported but that particular frame. I am assuming it may be due to a timeout or that it takes more time to load font awesome than the time QGIS takes in exporting, so my question is: Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try ticking the **Print as raster** under **Export settings**, which you can find on the right hand side of the print composer under **Composition** as shown in image.

[image: Screen Grab]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, @Richard McDonell! It worked perfectly.